# How to get the last value from the database

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to fetch the last value generated from a query from database ,so I used following code.But I get 0 instead of the last value.So, please check this.I am new in PHP.Thanks in advance.

```
$feedbackStudentInfo="INSERT INTO `feedback_system_db`.`feedback_student_info` (`fs_id`, `batch_id`,`course`,`semester`, `section`, `feedback_session`)VALUES('','$feedBatchId','$course_id','$Current_Sem' ,'$Current_section',2014)";

$test2=mysqli_query($con,$feedbackStudentInfo);

$fsid=mysql_insert_id();

echo $fsid;
```

Comment: Because you're mixing `mysqli_` and `mysql_` functions

Comment: is fs_id an auto-increment?

Comment: Yes fs_id is an auto_increment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$feedbackStudentInfo="INSERT INTO `feedback_system_db`.`feedback_student_info` (`fs_id`, `batch_id`,`course`,`semester`, `section`, `feedback_session`)VALUES('','$feedBatchId','$course_id','$Current_Sem' ,'$Current_section',2014)";

$test2=mysqli_query($con,$feedbackStudentInfo);

$fsid=mysqli_insert_id($con); // Use mysqli_insert_id instead of mysql_insert_id

echo $fsid;
```

Comment: Please check then your query runs successfully or not

Comment: Code updated, please check now. Pass $con to mysqli_insert_id().

Comment: Then, please accept my answer as solution. Also +1 :)

Comment: @Rajat, can you please accept my answer as solution?

Comment: Done @ProgrammingStudent , actually it was showing me a waiting time of 7 minutes , thats why I was late.

Answer (score 0):

It should be 
`$fsid=mysqli_insert_id();` instead of `$fsid=mysql_insert_id();`

Answer (score 0):

Last Value of that query? You could simply use sql.

You must have some primary key so use ´LIMIT 1´ and  ´ORDER BY id DESC´.
It reverses the order and limits it to 1 ( so the highest id is first result, limit  then only takes this 1 result).